# How do you plot on a premade matplotlib plot with IPyWidgets?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I have a scenario where I would like to initialize the plot and plot a bunch of stuff on it before I run a widget on it. However, the jupyter widget refuses to plot on my already made plot. Instead, nothing shows up. A simplified example of this is below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython import display 

fig=plt.figure(1,(2,2))
axs=fig.gca()

def testAnimate(x):
    axs.text(0.5,0.5,x)

xs=widgets.IntSlider(min=0,max=3,value=1) #Create our intslider such that the range is [1,50] and default is 10

gui = widgets.interactive(testAnimate, x=xs) #Create our interactive graphic with the slider as the argument
display.display(gui)    #display it
```

I would expect the value of x to show up on axs, but it does not. I realize that in this case I could just do plt.text, however in my actual project that is not viable. So, how do I get the value of x to show up on my plot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Jupyter Notebook, you first have to initialize the interactive matplotlib. You can do that by running either one of the following magic commands:

- `%matplotlib notebook`
- `%matplotlib widget`. This one requires [ipympl](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl) to be installed.

Then, execute:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython import display 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
text = ax.text(0.5, 0.5, "0")

def testAnimate(x):
    text.set_text(x)

xs=widgets.IntSlider(min=0,max=3,value=1) #Create our intslider such that the range is [1,50] and default is 10

gui = widgets.interactive(testAnimate, x=xs) #Create our interactive graphic with the slider as the argument
display.display(gui)    #display it
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, is there any way to get rid of that toolbar on the side that lets you change the view? I only want to be able to interact via the sliders.

Comment: For those interested in regards to that comment, see my answer where I mention leave out any `%matplotlib ... ` line at the top or to use `%matplotlib inline`.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. I had seen to put the plot creating in the function you call with the interactive wrapper. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69182917/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63186591/8508004).

Translating that to your code by moving the two lines inside the function would have your notebook cell be:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython import display 

def testAnimate(x):
    fig=plt.figure(1,(2,2))
    axs=fig.gca()
    axs.text(0.5,0.5,x)

xs=widgets.IntSlider(min=0,max=3,value=1) 

gui = widgets.interactive(testAnimate, x=xs) #Create our interactive graphic with the slider as the argument
gui
```

Note that this works with `%matplolib inline` or actually without it at all as detailed in the comment at the top of the code [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69182917/8508004).
I don't want the extra cruft and stuff that  `%matplotlib widget` or `%matplotlib notebook` makes and **makes the interactivity limited to the slider**, like you seem to prefer as well.

---

And because the interactive ability of ipywidgets will make the widget automatically, you can simplify further to:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets

def testAnimate(x):
    fig=plt.figure(1,(2,2))
    axs=fig.gca()
    axs.text(0.5,0.5,x)

gui = widgets.interactive(testAnimate, x=(0,3,1))
gui
```