# Sliders and Image Update (Python Jupyter Lab)

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I need help with the following problem - the code snippet I am using should update the image I want to display, but when I am sliding, nothing happens.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets 
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display

# Define initial values for the sliders
initial_slider1_value = 1.0
initial_slider2_value = 1.0
initial_slider3_value = 0.0
initial_slider4_value = 0.0

# Create sliders for the parameters that go into the homography matrix
slider1 = widgets.FloatSlider(value=initial_slider1_value, min=-3, max=3, step=0.01, description='Stretch X:')
slider2 = widgets.FloatSlider(value=initial_slider2_value, min=-3, max=3, step=0.01, description='Stretch Y:')
slider3 = widgets.FloatSlider(value=initial_slider3_value, min=-500, max=500, step=1, description='Move X:')
slider4 = widgets.FloatSlider(value=initial_slider4_value, min=-500, max=500, step=1, description='Move Y:')

# Create a function to update the displayed image based on slider values
def update_image(change):
    slider1_value = slider1.value
    slider2_value = slider2.value
    slider3_value = slider3.value
    slider4_value = slider4.value
    
    homography_matrix = np.array([[slider1_value, 0, slider3_value],
                                   [0, slider2_value, slider4_value],
                                   [0, 0, 1]])

    # Perform image warping and blending here using the homography matrix
    # Replace the following lines with your image processing code
    
    img1_pad, warped = warpPerspectivePadded(thermal_fused_image, color_fused_image, homography_matrix)

    blended = cv2.addWeighted(warped, 0.5, img1_pad, 0.5, 1.0)
    
    # Display the updated image
    image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(blended, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    clear_output(wait=True)
    display(image)

# Attach the update_image function to the slider's value change event
slider1.observe(update_image)
slider2.observe(update_image)
slider3.observe(update_image)
slider4.observe(update_image)

homography_start = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                            [0, 1, 0],
                            [0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.float32)

dummy1, dummy2 = warpPerspectivePadded(thermal_fused_image, color_fused_image, homography_start)

initial_image = cv2.addWeighted(dummy2, 0.5, dummy1, 0.5, 1.0)
initial_image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(initial_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
display(initial_image)

display(slider1, slider2, slider3, slider4)
```

Every variable that is not defined here is unnecessary and correctly imported.

I have tried changing the callback functions, but simply nothing triggers the desired behaviour.

Comment: This isn't nearly a minimal reproducible example. Always try running your shared code in a fresh kernel or session and see if it works. This won't for at least two reasons I've already come across. Help those trying to help you by following the guidance in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, see 'Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem ' under the section 'Help others reproduce the problem'.

Comment: By way of help, I will add that `interact()` or `interactive()` provide an easier way to do this where the observing and updating is more easily handled by ipywidgets itself. See a minimum example of that at the bottom [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74551129/8508004) and for adding in additional sliders, you may want to get some guidance [here](https://kapernikov.com/ipywidgets-with-matplotlib/). As for the method you are currently using, minimal code for a working use of the `.observe()` method is at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40165257/8508004 but it doesn't use a slider. You could ...

Comment: <continued> probably adjust it. Depending on where you are working with that code, you'll see the `print()` events that happen on updating go to the Log console. That is because that code doesn't have a way to handle the `Output()` built in yet & that is a symptom of that when you are working in JupyterLab 3 (& presumably 4). I won't go into how to rectify that in that example because you aren't looking to use `print()` in yours. However, I do wonder if you have an issue with not handling the updates in `Output()` because you seem to be maybe using code the is incomplete for modern ipywidgets.

Comment: Back to my suggestion of using `interact()` or `interactive()`, I'll note there is an example that uses multiple sliders for image processing that I edited to work from the current ipywidgets documentation. [Here](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/3ec0088f96fb1fab340fdd24657d6f9e) is the edited form that runs in an active Jupyter session. (The original source is cited there.) DEMO IT YOURSELF WITHOUT TOUCHING YOUR OWN SYSTEM: That notebook will run in an active Jupyter sessions launched from [here](https://github.com/fomightez/communication_voila/) by pressing the 'launch binder' badge.